# convert request from cURL to postman

Tags: php, curl, postman

I am trying to convert the following post request using postman with no luck

```
> curl "https://192.168.50.52/token" \
>     --request POST \
>     --include \
>     --insecure \
>     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
>     --data '["todo.all"]' \
>     --user test:test
```

Comment: Sorry to hear that. What isn't working?

Comment: i get ```{
    "title": "Insecure use of middleware over HTTP denied by configuration.",
    "type": "about:blank",
    "status": 500
}```

Comment: i dont know what to pass in header and in request body

Comment: Have you considered showing us what you're currently sending so we know? We have no clue what you're sending from postman

Comment: You haven't given us any useful information whatsoever. You haven't even told us what you're sending in postman yet. We can't possibly offer any assistance

Comment: I am trying to implement this https://github.com/tuupola/slim-api-skeleton

Comment: https://github.com/tuupola/slim-basic-auth/issues/12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `"secure" => false` setting in slim-api if you do not want to use https